# Integrate multiple iOS Apps into single iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, uistoryboard

I have more than two Apps which will be available on App Store, Those apps are small Apps for different departments/categories (let's suppose Medical App, Tourism/Travel App, Education App, etc).

Now I want to develop some "General app" which will contain above small apps as micro-apps,

There will be icons/buttons on Main Screen to navigate to any category (Health, Travel, Education etc) inside the General App, rest of the App Flow inside each category will remain same as in Mini Apps.

The mini-apps and General App will be available on App Store separately, so any new version/update in the source code of Mini Apps need to be updated into General App.

Is it possible to add more than 1 projects into one project assuming each project has it's own storyboard,xibs.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a single project with different build targets, and each build target could be one of your apps.

Also you can use xcconfig files to config the settings of the different build targets

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried to add different build target by dragging xcode project file but I can not import any file of that target into parent project. Will Classes, Storyboard etc will be accessible to main project? Can you suggest any link to add access any view controller of added target into new project?

Comment: When you drag a Xcode project, it's to add a dependent project not add a build target. I'll added two screenshots regarding adding build targets, hope it will help

Comment: I find only Duplicate Option to add new target, Can you please suggest how can I add Target of some Existing App instead of Duplicating the current Target.

Comment: You cannot, but to creat a new project and reorganise your files

Comment: Thanks, So what i understand is , Create a new target, add the names of all compile sources, resources, binaries, ,icons, xibs etc into that target manually?  No way to add existing target.  And in future if there is any new version of that mini-app and we want to update it in General App we will have to verify the Target Settings manually to check for any newly added resources or compiler sources files?

Comment: I assume that at the moment you have one project for each app and these projects share most of the files, so I recommend you create a new general project and use different build targets for different app, and in the future, if you wanna create a new app, you just need to add a new build target, and make minimum changes